# Drag Image into Div and Alert

Tags: javascript, html, css, image, drag

I need to drag a picture into a div and if it touches "yes" it would alert : YES, but if it touches "no" it would alert : NO !
I can't actually do it, you can see what i have here, i don't know why, but in my project i can at least drag the JS image and in jsfiddle i can't, so i basically need an if to do the alerts!

http://jsfiddle.net/vy635/1/

```
<div id="yes" style="background-color:lightyellow; width:64px; height:64px; border-width:2px; border-style:solid; border-color:black;"> 
    <center>yes</center> 
</div>
<br>
<div id="no" style="background-color:lightyellow; width:64px; height:64px; border-width:2px; border-style:solid; border-color:black;"> 
    <center>no</center> 
</div>
```

Thanks !

Comment: i donno what is the problem in dragging in jsfiddle, but it will work if you add movMeId.style.position= 'absolute'; in js code

Comment: and to know where you have placed the image, is by knowing the div elements ordinates and dimensions. I hope it gives you idea how to do it...

Comment: @pal singh 
movMeId.style.position= 'absolute'; actually it didn't work :/

Comment: it will work.. also remove window.onload

Comment: after both things, i can't still drag the object !

Comment: Check this: http://jsfiddle.net/vy635/2/

Comment: @palsingh hey thanks a lot, can you help me with something more ?

Comment: Like, when touching one of those divs, to do a jscript alert..

Comment: for that, just use the coordinates and dimensions on the DIV, and keep them comparing in the mousemove function, i can't write code because lack of time, you must give it a try.